# Is it OK to use the correlation state object to pass channel data in a message inspector?

Tags: c#, wcf

In a message inspector (`IClientMessageInspector` or `IDispatchMessageInspector`), only one of the methods receives an `IClientChannel` parameter. I want to have some channel data available in the other method, so I created a class to use as the correlation state object:

```
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    var typedCorrelationState = (CorrelationState)correlationState;

    /* ... */
}

public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
    var correlationState = new CorrelationState
    {
        SoapCorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        EndpointAddress = channel.RemoteAddress.Uri.ToString()
    };

    /* ... */

    return correlationState;
}

private class CorrelationState
{
    public Guid SoapCorrelationId { get; set; }

    public string EndpointAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Is it OK to use the correlation state like this, or is there a more proper way to pass along such data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is perfect.

An authoritative example: [WCF Extensibility – Message Inspectors](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/04/18/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors/). If you search the blog post for "correlationState" you'll see he is passing URI in the same way.